# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require at

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, jasmine

I have a question about using jasmine with Grunt. I keep getting an error,

**ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require at**

whenever I run my jasmine tests. Here is my jasmine entry for my Gruntfile.js :

```
jasmine: {
      js: {
        src: jsFiles,
        options: {
          specs: 'tests/*_spec.js',
          helpers: 'tests/helpers/*',
          vendor: 'vendor/*'
        }
      }
    },
```

I can run a dummy test without a require just fine, but when I include a require in a test, like so, I get the require error.

```
var testD = require('../src/events_to_actions');

describe("events_to_actions", function() {
  it("is dummy test", function() {
    expect(true).toEqual(true);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem.  Just install this node package and add this line to your Gruntfile and require should start working again.

https://github.com/cloudchen/grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs

```
jasmine: {
      js: {
        src: jsFiles,
        options: {
          specs: 'tests/*_spec.js',
          helpers: 'tests/helpers/*',
          vendor: 'vendor/*',
          template: require('grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs')
        }
      }
    },
```

Comment: this doesn't really work because require js has a different require statement than the one given in the example above.

Answer (score 5):

The solution that **@user3741597** is suggesting might work, but it is a bit of a backwards solution.

"grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs" was written for RequireJS, which is an AMD loader. On the other hand, you are using CommonJS syntax. If you want to continue to use "grunt-contrib-jasmine", then you need to find a CommonJS template, or else use the information that [Jasmine has node support built-in](http://jasmine.github.io/2.4/node.html) and take a different approach.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413099/how-use-require-inside-a-spec-grunt-karma-jasmine-in-node/34246531#34246531) may help as well.

Answer (score 0):

Leading on from the solution by **@justin-helmer**, there is a template that allows you to use require calls (CommonJS syntax) with grunt-contrib-jasmine:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-template-jasmine-nml

An example of grunt config using this:

```
jasmine: {
    options: {
        template: require('grunt-template-jasmine-nml'),
        helpers: 'spec/helpers/**/*.js',
        specs: 'spec/**/*.spec.js'
    }
}
```