# How use require inside a spec - grunt + karma + jasmine in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, jasmine, karma-runner

**Vague version question:**

- How can I use require inside a spec with grunt?

**Context:**

I'm working on an existent node project that has no tests yet, so I read some and realized to use karma and jasmine.

I read some tutos (including these):

- http://kwilson.me.uk/blog/use-karma-and-grunt-to-run-your-jasmine-tests-in-real-time/
- http://ahexamples.blogspot.com.br/2014/03/example-of-jasmine-karma-sonar-grunt.html

So I'm trying to run my specs with grunt and getting this error:

> X encountered a declaration exception
>       ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require in file:///(...)-spec.js (line 2) (1)

The line is something like:

```
var myHelper = require(...);
```

But if I use via terminal "node-jasmine test" it works like a charm...

My project structure:

> - controllers/
> - helpers/
> - models/
> - node_modules/
> - resources/
> - test/
> - test/spec/
> - views/
> - app.js
> - Gruntfile.js
> - package.json

In my spec (inside test/spec/) I use a require('../../helpers/helper.js') and that's ok for node-jasmine, but no with grunt.

node-jasmine test:

> .....
>
> Finished in 0.015 seconds 5 tests, 5 assertions, 0 failures, 0 skipped

grunt:

> Running "jasmine:pivotal" (jasmine) task Testing jasmine specs via
>   PhantomJS
>
> > > ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require at
> > >       app.js:1   Service Helper Tests    X encountered a declaration exception
> > >            ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require in file:///(...)/test/spec/serviceHelper-spec.js
> > >       (line 2) (1)
>
> 1 spec in 0.005s.
>
> > > 1 failures Warning: Task "jasmine:pivotal" failed. Use --force to continue.
>
> Aborted due to warnings.

I have all packages installed into node_modules (nothing in dependencies in package.json) and my Gruntfile.js is:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(grunt) {
    var $srcFiles = 'app.js';
    var $testFiles = 'test/spec/*-spec.js';
    var $outputDir = 'test/target'
    var $junitResults = $outputDir + '/junit-test-results.xml';
    var $jasmineSpecRunner = $outputDir + '/_SpecRunner.html';
    var $coverageOutputDir = $outputDir + '/coverage';


    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        // Jasmine test
        jasmine: {
            pivotal: {
                src: $srcFiles,
                options: {
                    specs: $testFiles,
                    outfile: $jasmineSpecRunner,
                    keepRunner: 'true'  // keep SpecRunner/outfile file
                }
            }
        },

        // coverage using Karma
        karma: {
            continuous: {
                singleRun: 'true',
                browsers: [ 'PhantomJS' ]
            },

            options: {
                plugins: [
                    'karma-jasmine',
                    'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
                    'karma-junit-reporter',
                    'karma-coverage'
                ],
                frameworks: [ 'jasmine' ],
                files: [ $srcFiles, $testFiles ],
                reporters: [ 'junit', 'coverage' ],
                junitReporter: {
                  outputFile: $junitResults
                },
                preprocessors: {
                    // source files must be a literal string
                    'helpers/*.js': [ 'coverage' ]
                },
                coverageReporter: {
                    type: 'lcov',
                    dir: $coverageOutputDir
                }
            }
        },

        // export Karma coverage to SonarQube
        karma_sonar: {
            your_target: {
                // properties for SonarQube dashboard
                project: {
                    key: 'net.ahexample:ahexample-jasmine-karma-sonar',
                    name: 'Jasmine with Karma and SonarQube Example',
                    version: '0.0.1'
                }

                // sources property is set at runtime (see below)
            }
        },

        clean: [ $outputDir ]
    });


    /*
     * Task to set karma_sonar's sources property.
     * This is needed because karma (coverage) stores its results in a
     * directory whose name uses the browser's user agent info
     * (name/version and the platform name).
     * The latter may well he different to the OS name and so its needs an
     * OS to platform translator.
     * For example, OS name for Apple Mac OS X is Darwin.
     */
    grunt.registerTask('set-karma-sonar-sources-property', function() {
        var $done = this.async();
        var $phantomjs = require('karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/phantomjs');
        var $spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
        var $phantomUserAgent = $spawn($phantomjs.path,
            // phantomjs script to print user agent string
            [ 'lib/phantomjs-useragent.js' ]
        );

        /*
         * Construct coverage LCOV file path from PhantomJS'
         * user agent string, then use it to set karma_sonar's
         * sources property.
         */
        $phantomUserAgent.stdout.on('data', function(msg) {
            var $useragent = require('karma/node_modules/useragent');
            var $agent = $useragent.parse(msg);
            // An example of dirName is 'PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X)'
            var $dirName = $agent.toAgent() + ' (' + $agent.os + ')';
            var $coverageResults = $coverageOutputDir + '/' + $dirName + '/lcov.info';
            var $sonarSources = makeSonarSourceDirs($srcFiles, $coverageResults);
            var $karmaSonarConfig = 'karma_sonar';
            var $ksConfig = grunt.config($karmaSonarConfig);

            grunt.log.writeln('coverage LCOV file: ' + $coverageResults);
            $ksConfig['your_target']['sources'] = $sonarSources;
            grunt.config($karmaSonarConfig, $ksConfig);

        });

        $phantomUserAgent.on('close', function(exitCode) {
            $done();
        });


        /*
         * Create sonar source object for each directory of source file pattern.
         */
        function makeSonarSourceDirs($filesPattern, $coverageResults) {
            var $path = require('path');
            var $dirs = [];

            grunt.file.expand(
                {
                    filter: function($filePath) {
                        $dirs.push({
                            path: $path.dirname($filePath),
                            prefix: '.',    // path prefix in lcov.info
                            coverageReport: $coverageResults,
                            testReport: $junitResults
                        });
                    }
                },
                $filesPattern
            );

            return $dirs;
        }
    });


    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jasmine');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-karma');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-karma-sonar');


    grunt.registerTask('test', [ 'jasmine', 'karma:continuous' ]);
    grunt.registerTask('sonar-only', [ 'set-karma-sonar-sources-property', 'karma_sonar' ]);
    grunt.registerTask('sonar', [ 'test', 'sonar-only' ]);
    grunt.registerTask('default', 'test');
}
```

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: I don't know if these approach could help... http://manuel.kiessling.net/2012/03/30/true-universal-javascript-modules-with-write-once-run-anywhere-jasmine-specs/

Answer (score 5):

### How

It depends:

1. If you have some application code that you need to test against a browser (e.g. `Angular`, `Backbone`, etc.) - Use `Karma` and don't use `require`. Then just make sure your `helpers.js` file loads before the tests themselves.

   ```
   // @file Gruntfile.js
   // https://github.com/karma-runner/grunt-karma
   grunt.initConfig({        
     karma: {
       client: {
         options: {
           files: ['client/*.js', 'helpers/*.js', 'test/*.js']
         }
       }
     }
   });

   // @file helpers.js
   (function () {
     window.helpers = {
       foo: function () {
         return 'bar';
       }
     };
   })();

   // @file spec.js
   (function (helpers) {

     it('does the thing', function () {
       expect(helpers.foo()).toBe('bar');
     });

   })(window.helpers);
   ```
2. If you don't need to run your tests against a browser (i.e. you are strictly testing `NodeJS` code), you can simplify your setup by removing `Karma` and strictly using `Jasmine`:

   ```
   // @file Gruntfile.js
   // https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jasmine
   grunt.initConfig({
     jasmine: {
       server: {
         src: 'server/*.js',
         options: {
           specs: 'test/*.js',
           helpers: 'helpers/*.js'
         }
       } 
     }
   });

   // @file helpers.js
   (function () {
     module.exports = {
       foo: function () {
         return 'bar';
       }
     };
   })();

   // @file spec.js
   (function () {
     var helpers = require('helpers'); // require is available

     it('does the thing', function () {
       expect(helpers.foo()).toBe('bar');
     });

   })();
   ```

### Why

`require` doesn't exist because you are using `Karma` to run your tests. `Karma` simply loads files in a browser of your choosing and executes them in the order you provide in your `karma.conf.js`. It internally uses the test framework you provide (in this case `Jasmine`) to run tests against the browser(s) you provide (in this case `PhantomJS`).

As is true with all JavaScript, the variable context is defined by the closure it is contained within.

- The `Jasmine` binary internally uses `NodeJS`, which [emulates CommonJS require](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/6fff47ffacfe663efeb0d31ebd700a65bf5521ba/deps/v8/test/promises-aplus/lib/require.js), making the `require` function available to you within the context of your node application.
- The `Karma` runner does what is the equivalent of writing `<script src="[path]">` tags to the browser, which then each load the corresponding file into `PhantomJs`. As a result, your javascript context is global, and your files only have access to the global context. In a browser, the global context is defined by everything attached to the `window` object, and `window.require` does not inherently exist.