# Testing Backbone with Karma, Grunt, and Jasime >> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, gruntjs

First off, I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23449220/referenceerror-cant-find-variable-require-at) and it gave me more errors (see bottom).

I get these error:

> **ReferenceError**: Can't find variable: require at test/spec/test.js:1
>
> **TypeError**: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'text.replace') at 
>       bower_components/underscore/underscore.js:1180  src/js/script.js:12  src/js/script.js:56  src/js/script.js:194
>
> **ReferenceError**: Can't find variable: require at test/spec/test.js:1

When trying to use Grunt.

Here is my Grunt file:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
jasmine: {
            src: 'src/js/*.js',
            options: {
                specs: 'test/spec/*.js',
                helpers: 'test/spec/*.js',
                vendor: [
                    'bower_components/jquery/jquery.js',
                    'bower_components/underscore/underscore.js',
                    'bower_components/backbone/backbone.js'
                ]
            }
        }
    });

grunt.registerTask('default', ['clean', 'jasmine']);
```

Here is my Test file:

```
var chai = require('chai')
var Backbone = require('backbone');
var _ = require('underscore');
describe('Underscore & Backbone to be defined', function() {
    it('should be loaded', function() {
        chai.should.exist(_);
        chai.should.exist(Backbone);
    })
})
```

I am not using requirejs by the way.

---

When adding grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs, `enter code here`I get these errors:

> >> Error: Module name "jquery" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
>
> >> http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded at
>
> >> .grunt/grunt-contrib-jasmine/require.js:8 aa
>
> >> .grunt/grunt-contrib-jasmine/require.js:12 v
>
> >> .grunt/grunt-contrib-jasmine/require.js:26 h
>
> >> .grunt/grunt-contrib-jasmine/require.js:31
>
> >> test/spec/test.js:1
>
> >> TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'text.replace') at
>
> >> bower_components/underscore/underscore.js:1180
>
> >> src/js/script.js:12
>
> >> src/js/script.js:56
>
> >> src/js/script.js:194
>
> >> Error: notloaded: Module name "jquery" has not been loaded yet for 
>   context: _. Use require([])
>
> >> http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded at
>
> >> _SpecRunner.html:46
>
> >> .grunt/grunt-contrib-jasmine/require.js:12 v
>
> >> .grunt/grunt-contrib-jasmine/require.js:26 h
>
> >> .grunt/grunt-contrib-jasmine/require.js:31
>
> >> test/spec/test.js:1